# Compare entered date and database date

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

In a booking form, i want to compare the entered date in the textbox(text mode is date) and all the dates in the database. So if there is an order already booked on that day, it will display already booked select another date otherwise it will carry on the form filling.(in vb.net-visual studio 2012)

this is the code
Protected Sub tbdate_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbdate.TextChanged

```
    Dim adaptor As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Try
        objConn.Open()
        Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("select order_date from bookorder where order_date=' " & tbdate.Text & "'", objConn)
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        adaptor.SelectCommand = sqlcmd
        adaptor.Fill(ds)
        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Label8.Visible = True
            Label8.Text = "Enter  different date"
        End If
        adaptor.Dispose()
        ds.Clear()

    Catch
        e.ToString()
    Finally
        objConn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: That's very nice, and what prevents you from doing so? Cause till now your question is just a statement. Show what you have tried so far, what blocks you from executing your ideas...

Comment: Add some code so we can see what you have tried

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question to include sample data as ddl+dml and your efforts so far. As is, this is not even a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where CAST(datecolumn as DATE) = textbox.date
```

Maybe you have to cast your textbox's date in order to match DB's format...
Use DateTime.ParseExact method